# In Java what is the relationship between a nested class and its outer class?

Tags: java, reference, nested, inner-classes, nested-class

When a nested class in instantiated how does it reference the outer class? Does it always extend the outer class or reference it another way? I was told that the inner extends the outer but then why doesn't the following example work?

**For Example:**

```
public class OuterClass {

    public String fruit = "apple";

    public class InnerClass {
        public String fruit = "banana";

        public void printFruitName(){
            System.out.println(this.fruit);
            System.out.println(super.fruit);
        }
    }

}
```

The above does not compile with an error for `super.fruit` saying that 'fruit' cannot be resolved. However if the inner class is specified to extend the outer class then it works:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public String fruit = "apple";

    public class InnerClass extends OuterClass {
        public String fruit = "banana";

        public void printFruitName(){
            System.out.println(this.fruit);
            System.out.println(super.fruit);
        }
    }

}
```

This seems to show that the inner class does not extend the outer class unless specifically specified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is *no* implicit sub-type relationship: your observation/conclusion is correct. (In the first case, `super` has the type of "Object" and "Object.fruit" does indeed not exist.)

An [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) (as opposed to "static nested class"), as shown, must be created within context of an instance of the outer class; but this is orthogonal to sub-typing.

To access a member of the outer class, use `OuterClass.this.member` or, if `member` is not shadowed, just `member` will resolve; *neither* `super.member` nor `this.member` will resolve to the outer class member.

Extending the outer class "fixes" the compiler error, but the code with `this.fruit` *doesn't* access the member of the enclosing OuterClass instance - it simply accesses the member *of the InnerClass instance* inherited from the superclass it extends.

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence please? I didn't know about `OuterClass.this` and was playing with it in the code posted in the question here, but when I have the inner class extend the outer class then both `OuterClass.this.fruit` and `super.fruit` do give me the outer instance's `fruit` value.

Comment: @MikeB This *appears* to be the case, even though it is not, *because* the member was set (to the same value)  when a new instance of OuterClass was created - e.g. for the *real* OuterClass instance and the superclass for the InnerClass instance. Change the `fruit` member variable of the OuterClass instance after it has been initialized but before creating an inner class instance - then you'll see a difference.

Comment: You're right of course, I even did that in my original code but I saw a pear and overlooked the fact that the second set of output should have had 2 pears!

Comment: +1 and thanks for getting the terminology right - many people say "inner class" when they mean "nested class".